# Creating full-screen DT table widget in shiny gadget

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to build a shiny gadget to browse my data in a datatable using the DT library. I would like the DT widget to fill the entire shiny page or screen, but the table is rendered with a low fixed height. How can I get the table to fill the UI?

I have already set the height paramerter of dataTableOutput to 100% and I have tried different UI containers such ass fillPage instead of the miniUI without any success.

Here is a condensed version of my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)
library(DT)

ViewDT <- function(data) {

  ui <- miniPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1", height = "100%")
    )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      table <- DT::datatable(data, 
                             extensions = c('Buttons','Scroller'), 
                             options = list(dom = 'BrtS', 
                                            buttons = I('colvis'),
                                            scrollY = 200,
                                            deferRender = TRUE,
                                            paging = T
                                            )
                             )
      })
  }

  runGadget(ui, server, viewer = dialogViewer("Data"))
}

ViewDT(iris)
```

The result: [The table fills about half of the dialog viewer instead of its entirety.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZSWN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `fillContainer = TRUE`:

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)
library(DT)

ViewDT <- function(data) {

  ui <- miniPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1", height = "100%")
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      table <- DT::datatable(data, 
                             extensions = c('Buttons','Scroller'), 
                             options = list(dom = 'BrtS', 
                                            buttons = I('colvis'),
                                            scrollY = 200,
                                            deferRender = TRUE,
                                            paging = TRUE
                             ),
                             fillContainer = TRUE
      )
    })
  }

  runGadget(ui, server, viewer = dialogViewer("Data"))
}

ViewDT(iris)
```